# Is it possible to stream an animation in real time as it is being rendered?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to figure out how to livestream in real time the output of my animation. Is this something that is possible in blender? I'm trying to find a service or add on or something that can allow a cluster of blender renders take the frames and audio and stream them as they are being rendered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a blender external service/functionality and not about a behaviour that can be created in Blender by Blender.

Comment: @Leander I think this is on topic, since it in its core is about whether it is possible to stream rendered frames out of blender, which is a question about blenders functionality. The OP simply mentioned the possibility to external services as being a solution.

Answer (score 2):

differently from still images, where you need to save the render result intentionally, an animation is always "saved" by blender, either as image sequence or a movie file (if you didn't specify anything, by default is a png image sequence in /tmp folder).

So, to "stream" an animation you need to choose how you would "stream" a (predictable) amount of still frames or a (constantly changing, while frames are rendered) single movie file...

Add to that the fact that each frame usually needs seconds to days to render, depending on computing power and scene complexity, and I guess you can't count to stream a **realtime** animation while you are rendering it...

Of course you could use a video capture system to "stream" the rendering result window as a video stream to receivers, so that they could remotely see the progress of the rendering (in rendering realtime, not animation realtime)...

Maybe if you specify better what you need, a better answer can be given.

Comment: I think he needs to stream it in a way how i.e. a video on a webpage is played. You can watch it while it is not entirely downloaded (rendered in this case).

Comment: @m.ardito Sorry i didn't explain it well. What I want to achieve is as jan said I need to be able to stream the video including audio as it is being rendered in real time. The output would ideally be sent to a streaming service that will broadcast the frames+audio as streaming service receives them.

Comment: ok, maybe I get it now :) I can't help directly, but maybe this will give some hint: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257326/convert-jpeg-sequence-to-movie-stream-in-realtime-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to render my frames to a folder on my computer that is synced with my Google Drive, and then, as the frames come in, I can see how it's doing from my phone. This isn't a perfect solution of course, as you can't view the actual animation, only frames, but it's still a workable option.